# Internationalization Next Js 13 and Adding Local Fonts

Tags: next.js13

I am attempting to add translations to my Next 13 website so I have this folder structure

```
rootFOlder
- app
-- [lang]
--- layout.js
- public
-- fonts
--- font.woff2
```

Now when I try to add localFonts to the layouyt.js file like this I keep getting an error

```
const ttcommons = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "/fonts/tt-commons/TTCommons-DemiBold.woff2",
      weight: '600',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: '/fonts/tt-commons/TTCommons-Medium.woff2',
      weight: '500',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: '/fonts/tt-commons/TTCommons-Regular.woff2',
      weight: 'normal',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: '/fonts/tt-commons/TTCommons-Light.woff2',
      weight: '300',
      style: 'normal',
    },
  ],
})
```

Error:

```
app\[lang]\layout.js

Module not found: Can't resolve './/fonts/tt-commons/TTCommons-DemiBold.woff2'
```

What could be the issue?